# Can they be homotopic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces, $f\colon X\rightarrow Z$ and $g\colon Y\rightarrow Z$ be continuous functions, and $Z$ be contractible. Can $f$ and $g$ be homotopic?

Note that, we know that the continuous functions $f,g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ are homotopic if $Y$ is contractible. Can we use the diagram below to answer the above question?

[image]

Comment: As you've stated your problem, $f$ and $g$ cannot be homotopic since they have different domains ($f$ has domain $X$ and $g$ has domain $Y$).

Comment: What do you mean by $I_X$?

Comment: You diagram does not agree with the definitions of $f,g$.

Comment: @William If there is a strong connection between X and Y, it still can't be done?

Comment: @juandiegorojas it is the idendity map of $X$

Comment: @PaulFrost if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, then can't it be said that $g\circ I_X$ and f are homotopic?

Comment: @MBKandemir For the special case that $X=Y$, and $Z$ is contractible, (which is just the same as the diagram shows) any continuous map between $X$ and $Z$ is homotopic to a constant map. William's comment is correct since this statement is not true for the general case.

Comment: @MBKandemir This might answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474389/contractible-spaces-and-homotopic-maps

Comment: @Kevin.S Why is this not achieved when $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic? Or does a weaker condition of homotopy occur?

Comment: By definition homotopic functions have the same domain and codomain. If you want to compare functions from two different domains, you have a choose a way of connecting them together. For example if $h\colon X \to Y$ is any function then it makes sense to compare $f$ and $g\circ h$, since these are now both functions with domain $X$ and codomain $Z$. However it's possible that $f\sim h\circ g$ but $f \not\sim h'\circ g$ for different functions (even if they are both homeomorphisms), so to be unambiguous it's important that you specify.

Comment: The central thing here is: given three spaces $A,B$ and $C$, then let $h:A\to B$, $f:B\to C$ and $g:A\to C$. The question turns out to be "Is $g\circ i\simeq f\circ h$?" But now how will you conclude that $g\simeq f$ without any further condition but homeomorphism??...; they have different domains.

Comment: Since the information now is not enough to conclude the case for homeomorphism, which links the two spaces together more strongly than homotopic equivalence, we can't discuss the validity for homotopic equivalence (more general than homeomorphism).

Comment: @Kevin.S if $X$ and $Y$ are homotopically equivalent, then can $f$ and $g$ be homotopic? Actually this is exactly what I want to ask?

Comment: If you choose a specific homotopy equivalence $h\colon X \to Y$, then it makes sense to ask wether $f$ is homotopic to $g\circ h$.

Comment: @William So, if $f:X\rightarrow Z$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$, $Z$ is contractible and $X$ is homotopically equivalent to $Y$, then can we say that $f$ is homotopic to $g$? .Did i get it right?

Comment: No, if $f$ and $g$ have different domains then you can never say they are homotopic. What *is* true is that $f$ is homotopic to $g\circ h$ for any $h\colon X \to Y$, because they are both maps from $X$ to the same contractible space.

Comment: OK thank you very much for your interest to anyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that *by definition* two functions can only be homotopic if they have the same domain and codomain. In your case $f$ and $g$ have the same codomain but different domains, so it doesn't make sense to ask if they are homotopic.

However if you pick an $h\colon X \to Y$ it now makes sense to compare $f$ and $g\circ h$, as they are both functions from $X$ to $Z$. Since $Z$ is contractible, we in fact have that $f\sim g\circ h$ for any $h$.